# "-bash: ls: command not found" error in Terminal on Mac. How to correct it?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal.app, .profile

I edited the .profile file to add a new PATH. I believe I set it wrong such that most commands become unavailable. Since I can't use ls or vi commands to edit .profile again, any idea how I can correct the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems more like a superuser.com question. Anyway, I would try to fix it by using the full path of vi to edit your .profile.

```
/usr/bin/vi /home/username/.profile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search for vi executable and run it directly. It is usually **/usr/bin/vi**

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename the .profile and relogon to get defaults back.